# Solving recurrence T(n) = T(n - 1) + n^2 using substitution method.

Tags: inequality, recurrence-relations, computational-complexity

I am trying to solve a recurrence using substitution method (I am asking for help/confirmation about this solving method, so don't answer with a solution developed by iteration method or something else).
I want to precise that I have just started studying recurrence relations, so I am asking for confirmation of my work.

Given:
$$
T(n) = \begin{cases}
1 & n = 1
\\
T(n - 1) + n^2 & n \gt 1
\end{cases}
$$

I guess that $T(n) = O(n^3)$, so:
$$
T(n) = T(n \space - \space 1) + n^2 \le c(n - 1)^3 + n^2\\
c(n - 1)^3 + n^2 = cn^3 - 3cn^2 + 3cn - c + n^2
$$

then I continued like this:
$$
cn^3 - 3cn^2 + 3cn - c + n^2 \le cn^3\\
3cn^2 - 3cn + c - n^2 \ge 0\\
$$

from now on, this is the part about I am not sure if I did it right:
$$
n(3cn - 3c - n) \ge -c\\
3cn - 3c - n \ge -\frac{c}{n}\\
n - 3c \ge -\frac{3c^2 - c}{n}\\
n \ge\ -\frac{3c^2 - c}{n} + 3c
$$
Now, I am not sure if i did that right.
I know that this recurrence is a $O(n^3)$, but I want to know if my proof is true.
I want to say that this isn't a homework or something like that, it's a simple exercise that came up to my mind.

EDIT:
Let's notice that:
$$
3cn^2 - 3cn + c - n^2 = n^2(3c - 1) - 3cn + c \ge 0
$$
so, all I need to do is to solve this quadratic inequality in order to find for which c values is verified.

Now, I have to calculate the discriminant to check if this inequality has solutions, so:
$$
(-3c)^2 - 4(3c - 1)(c) = 9c^2 - 12c^2 - 4c = -3c^2 - 4c = c(3c + 4)
$$

Only when the discriminant is greater than zero, the inequality has solutions, and in this case:
$$
3c + 4 > 0\\
3c > -4\\
c > -\frac{4}{3}
$$

From this result, it's proven that $T(n) = O(n^3), \space \forall c > -\frac{4}{3}$
I thought about this proof, is it wrong or did I missed something?

Comment: One question, what is substitution method? I can't help you if I don't know what method are you using.

Comment: Substitution method is a solving recurrences method that relies on the induction principle.
This method is used to prove upper/lower bounds by induction, just we said in the comments in your answer.
For further information, I guess it would be better if you google it.

Answer (score 1):

To solve the recurrence exactly, you need to assume a more general ansatz:
$$T(n) = An^3+Bn^2+Cn.$$ Substitution yields:
$$An^3+Bn^2+Cn = A(n-1)^3+B(n-1)^2+C(n-1) + n^2.$$
If we let $n = 1,2,3$, we get the system of equations
$$A+B+C = 1,$$
$$7A+3B+C = 4,$$
$$19A+5B+C = 9.$$

Comment: Thank you, but I do not want to solve the recurrence, I just want to find an upper bound.
Have I done it right?

Comment: you are introducing another constant $k$ into your solution.  I'm not sure what this represents.

Comment: omg, I am sorry, i didn't notice that.
I guess that I typed "k", by mistake.

Comment: All right, I have correct the error, now, what do you think?
Is my proof correct?

Comment: In the second line of you inequalities, you should have a negative: $-c/n$ on the right side.

Comment: Yes, I missed that, now I have corrected the mistake.
Does my proof work?
Have I used the substitution method in the right way?